# Show horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of screen, not at the bottom of element

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have website with long content - so website must be vertically scrollable. However, there is also horizontally scrollable div at the bottom of page. Unfortunately, horizontal scrollbar of this element is not visible until user scrolls down. Is there any way to show horizontal scrollbar always at the bottom of screen? [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5vz2p13u/) is example.

```css
.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 5rem;
}

.scrollable-content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.wide-content {
  width: 150vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Div which is not horizontally scrollable
  </div>
  <div class="scrollable-content">
    Div which is horizontally scrollable
    <div class="wide-content">
      Some wide content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am also having the same question, wondering if you have found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You must add some `-webkit-scrollbar` selectors in your css to **show the scrollbar** every time. Look at the example below:

```css
.scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 11px;
}
.scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.scrollable-content::-webkit-scrollbar-track { 
    background-color: #fff; 
    border-radius: 8px; 
} 


.container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 5rem;
}

.scrollable-content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 30vh;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.wide-content {
  width: 150vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="content">
        Div which is not horizontally scrollable
   </div>
   <div class="scrollable-content" style="width:500px; overflow-x:scroll; border:dotted 1px; white-space: nowrap;padding-bottom:10px;">
     Div which is horizontally scrollable
      <div class="wide-content">
           Some wide content
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I hope the solution is as you imagined it

Answer (score -1):

I changed `scrollable-content` to this:

```
.scrollable-content {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 89vh;
  width: 1000%;
}
```

and body to this:

```
body {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

I hope this helps